# Incorrect syntax for inserting data into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am attempting to use the following insert command in SQL Sever Management Studio 2012:

```
INSERT INTO 'F' ('date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'amount_change','percent_change')  
VALUES ('2012-12-19', 11.79, 11.85, 11.62, 11.73, 54884700, -0.06, -0.508906)
```

When I attempt this the error I get is

> parameters supplied for object F which is not a function

I can confirm that there is a table `F`. I have tried various syntax using `dbo.f`, `"F"`, `'F'`, `[dbo].[F]`, all to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the single quotes from the table name and the column names. If you want them escaped use brackets [].

```
INSERT INTO [F] ([date], [open], [high], [low], [close], [volume], 
[amount_change], [percent_change])  
VALUES ('2012-12-19', 11.79, 11.85, 11.62, 11.73, 54884700, -0.06, -0.508906)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, many thanks. Do you have any suggestions on how I could have better asked the question, as I seem to continuously get down-voted.

Comment: No problem. Not sure how you could have better asked the question.  I actually haven't submitted too many questions.  I understood just fine what the problem was with how you asked the question.

Comment: Or - alternatively - use the ANSI standard double quotes `"` instead of the non-standard `[..]` quoting (I think this is enabled by default in newer versions of SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

Just a tidbit for your information, there is session setting that allows double quotes (ISO rules) for table and column names.

```
-- Set option on
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO

-- Insert data
INSERT INTO "F" ("date", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "amount_change","percent_change")  
VALUES ('2012-12-19', 11.79, 11.85, 11.62, 11.73, 54884700, -0.06, -0.508906)
```

Check out this technet article for more details.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx

TSQL is a big product with many little idiosyncrasies.

Sincerely

John

[www.craftydba.com](http://www.craftydba.com)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [F] for the table and make sure you are in the same database. It appears to work fine when I test it.

```
INSERT INTO [F] ('date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'amount_change','percent_change')
VALUES ('2012-12-19', 11.79, 11.85, 11.62, 11.73, 54884700, -0.06, -0.508906)
```